# Android:Using Timer to Update Views Dynamically With Kotlin

Tags: android, timer, kotlin

I am trying to use a timer to update a text view using a list of strings. Using this timer I am able to print the items in the list 1 by 1, however the text view jumps straight to the last item. Can anyone indicate the correct method for updating a text view using a timer such that each update shows independantly when the app is run?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val changingWord = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.changingWordTextView)
    var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer

    val titleShift = mutableListOf<String>("_____", "Words", "Verse", "Haiku", "Dream", "World", "Smile", "Story", "Glory", "Birth", "Plant", "Truth", "Voice", "Value", "Sound", "Human")

    fun WordChanger(num: Int) {

        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) { // starts at 3 seconds

            override fun onTick(secondsUntilDone: Long) {

            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                Log.i("We're done!", "No more countdown")
                changingWord.text = titleShift[num]
                println(titleShift[num])
            }
        }.start()

    }

    WordChanger(0)
    WordChanger(1)
    WordChanger(2)
    WordChanger(3)
    WordChanger(4)

}
```

}

Here is the XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/changingWordTextView"
    android:layout_width="222dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/architects_daughter"
    android:text="______"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.169"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.24" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="151dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="93dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/architects_daughter"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/haikusButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/quotesButton"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Inset"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="276dp"
    android:text="Quotes"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/haikusButton"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/changingWordTextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/poemsButton"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Inset"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="158dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="136dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="135dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    android:text="Poems"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/changingWordTextView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="222dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/architects_daughter"
    android:text="Of The Day"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.915"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.224" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/haikusButton"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Inset"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="286dp"
    android:text="Haikus"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/quotesButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="141dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/architects_daughter"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quotesButton" />
```

Here is the manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dnarial.blankoftheday">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are starting all the timers at once and not one by one like you want to. There are a few ways that you can do this

1. Just use one single `CountDownTimer` and update the data inside `onTick` method based on how much time has elapsed

   ```
   fun WordChanger(num: Int) {

   countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(3000 * <number of words>, 1000) { // starts at 3 seconds

       override fun onTick(secondsUntilDone: Long) {
           if (secondsUntilDone > 9000) {
               Log.i("We're done!", "No more countdown")
               changingWord.text = titleShift[0]
               println(titleShift[0])
           } else if (secondsUntilDone > 6000) {
               Log.i("We're done!", "No more countdown")
               changingWord.text = titleShift[1]
               println(titleShift[1])
           }
           .
           .
           .
           etc
       }

       override fun onFinish() {
       }
   }.start()}
   ```
2. If you still insist on using the above approach than what you need to do is provide the time as an input as well. So your code would look like this

   ```
   fun WordChanger(num: Int, time: Long) {

   val countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(time, 1000) { // starts at 3 seconds

       override fun onTick(secondsUntilDone: Long) {

       }

       override fun onFinish() {
           Log.i("We're done!", "No more countdown")
           changingWord.text = titleShift[num]
           println(titleShift[num])
       }
   }.start()}

    WordChanger(0, 3000) 
    WordChanger(1, 6000) 
    WordChanger(2, 9000) 
    WordChanger(3, 12000) 
    WordChanger(4, 15000)
   ```

Let me know if you need any explanation

Comment: I went with the second method to make it less verbose and it works perfectly. Thank you. Can you explain how it decides to use  WordChanger(4, 15000) over WordChanger(0, 3000)? Does it inherently know that 15 comes before 3 and thus executes sequentially?

Comment: Never mind, they all execute at once with different timer duration.

Comment: Yeah you got it. They all execute at once. Please accept the answer if it's correct and worked for you